# Cakephp 3.0 default folder structure Customization

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to customize the default folder structure of Cakephp. I have ten modules which are all huge use-cases, so for maintenance purpose I want to customize the Cakephp default folder structure.

For e.g.:

Now the `src` folder contains controllers, template, and model, but I want to maintain separate folders for each modules in `config` folder, so that modules folder will contain its own controller, models, and templates.

Is it possible to create something like this?

Comment: there are plugins in cakephp, you could use plugin to achieve your requirement.
Check : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CakePHP Plugins. They are like mini-apps or modules that were you can group parts of your application:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html

Comment: @jose Lorenzo thanks for the rply..but is any way to rename the folder called src.if i rename in the sense what it will happen?

Comment: You will need to change the composer.json of your application to tell composer where the files of your plugin can be found.